# From Soap XML to Excel file

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to load a XML into DataSet for creating a Excel file with its data. The XML is a SOAP response.
With a XML standard I have no problem with the following code, but I have nothing working with SOAP XML…

```
//.… Previous code
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(soapResponse); //soapResponse is a string with <?xml… <soap:Envelope….
xdoc.Save("temp.xml"); 

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("temp.xml", XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString ();
            }
        }

//Save and close excel…
```

Is this not work with SOAP XML?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update Added Soap Response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeatherInformationResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
      <GetWeatherInformationResult>
        <WeatherDescription>
          <WeatherID>1</WeatherID>
          <Description>Thunder Storms</Description>
          <PictureURL>http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/thunderstorms.gif</PictureURL>
        </WeatherDescription>
        <WeatherDescription>
          <WeatherID>2</WeatherID>
          <Description>Partly Cloudy</Description>
          <PictureURL>http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/partlycloudy.gif</PictureURL>
        </WeatherDescription>
        ....
      </GetWeatherInformationResult>
    </GetWeatherInformationResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: edit: ds.Tables (DataSet) only has one table with one row (column body… ) With a XML plain, it has a table with one row for each "section" of XML.

Comment: Basicly, the table is {Body}… how can I select the right node? I updated the answer with the XML.

Comment: You would have to create a schema and inject it inline with the xml or reference it as an .xsd. But you are already loading an XmlDocument (I would personally go with XDocument instead) so why don't you just use that instead of the extra steps of writing a file and loading a DataSet?